# Meu app aborta ao tentar consumir rest

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, xamarin

Tem um serviço rest que meu App android necessita consumir. Para isso tenho que enviar uma parâmetro em formato json. Acontece que ele aborta no momento em que vai consumir o **Service**. Esse é o código que tenho para consumir o **Service**:

```
public async Task<string> PostIndicador(string jsonValue)
        {
            string retorno = null;
            if (NetworkCheck.IsInternet())
            {
                string url_base = $"meu_ip";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url_base));
                using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = uri })
                {
                    var responeMessage =
                    await client.PostAsync("/Service/Service.svc/GetIndicator", new StringContent("jsonValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                    var resultcontent = await responeMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    retorno = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultcontent)).ToString();
                }                
            }

            return retorno;
        }
```

O código da chamada é esse:

```
private void Click_Service(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataService dataService = new DataService();
            string jvalue = "{"\"Matriz\":12, \"Filial\":21"}";
            dataService.PostIndicador(jvalue);
        }
```

Acontece que quando chega nesta linha

```
var responeMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Service/Service.svc/GetIndicator", new StringContent("jsonValue", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

o sistema aborta. Coloquei um try..catch somente para essa linha e não cai no catch. Ele aborta o método por completo. O que será que pode ser? Alguém já passou por isso e quer compartilhar a experiência?

**EDIT1**

Alterei meu método para essa nova abordagem

```
public async Task PostIndicador(IndicadorPost indicador)
        {
            try
            {
                string url_base = $"http://meu_ip/Service/Service.svc/GetIndicator";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url_base));
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indicador);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                //if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                //{
                //    throw new Exception("Erro ao atualizar tabela de liberacao");
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string er = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

agora quando chega nessa linha:
`response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);`

Entra no exception. A mensagem é:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Não sei qual o objeto que está nulo. A minha desconfiança é se realmente eu necessito instanciar o Serviço, já que é um **WCF**. Prque fora ele, não vejo nada que eu não tenha instanciado.

**EDIT2**

a mensagem

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

já resolvi. É que o **client** estava declarado no começo da classe, mas não instanciado. Resolvido. Agora quando chega aqui
`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);`

Não dá erro algum, mas ele sai do laço. Como é um post, esse é o comportamento normal ou não? Como testo um post.

**EDIT3**

Consegui fazer parar no break agora. O erro? Sim, ele de novo:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Esse é o erro que está dando  no momento de consumir o serviço. Se ele não conseguir se conectar com o serviço, esse erro pode explodir no App? O que mais pode estar nulo ou não instanciado? Necessito instanciar o Service(WCF)? Essas são as dúvidas que tenho.

**EDIT4**

em realidade o erro de

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tem a ver com o try..catch do botão de chamada e não do método, como o Listview não é amarrado ao result do serviço dá esse erro. O que passa é que eu fiz uma aplicação console para testar e dá a mesma coisa, ou seja, simplesmente aborta ao tentar consumir o serviço. Vou fazer um serviço aqui Web API e ver se tem algo a ver a tecnologia utilizada para construção dos serviços. Só preciso ter a certeza se a forma como eu fiz está ou não correta.

**EDIT5**

Tenho a certeza que o problema está na classe `HttpClient`, pois fiz um Console e não consegui consumir o **Serviço**. Então instalei a classe RestSharp e consegui consumir o serviço. O problema é que a RestSharp não consigo instalar no Xamarin.Forms. Até abri uma thread sobre isso aqui no SOpt.

Comment: Poste a `exception` que está ocorrendo, se nao fica complicado de ajudar

Comment: @LMaker, não tem exception. Não entra no catch e quando chega na linha citada, ele simplesmente aborta. Não sei como fazer para forçar mostrar uma exception.Vou colocar um try..catch no botão de chamada e ver se lá ele mostra alguma exception. Já volto.

Comment: @LMaker, coloquei um try..catch na chamada e não cai no catch. Aborta e fica como se estivesse funcionando, mas não no debug não consigo ir até o fim na método do Serviço.

Comment: Só para testar, tira o await e coloca o .Result no final

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, fiz isso e quando chega no Result. Deu status Canceled. Acho que a abordagem para consumir rest com Post não foi a melhor. Preciso achar outra forma.

Comment: @pnet não acho que esse problema esteja acontecendo porque você está rodando ono modo debug.

Comment: Olá @PauloHDSousa, também acho, mas até o momento do comment eu tinha essa desconfiaça. Fiz uma edição no post informando o que mais eu consegui caminhar, mas ainda sem solução.

Comment: @LMaker, a exception é `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Esse erro diz que vc está fazendo referencia a algum objeto que está `null`.

Comment: @LMaker, obrigado por responder. Mas eu estou refazendo tudo que eu fiz e não tenho nada nulo ou não instanciado. O serviço, passando a URL dele pelo SOAP UI ele retorna algo. É um serviço REST e ainda na dúvida quanto a isso.